# Python3 - How to extract all elements within a row tag <tr> and append them as rows to a dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract rows from an html table and append them to a DataFrame or directly into an Excel spreadsheet.

I want to maintain the original structure of the table because it maps the physical layout of a matrix system. For example, the data I am attempting to extract follows this form.

```
<div id="FA_DSC"><p>Table_Title</p><table border="1" cellpadding="4"style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td>X68</td>
<td>X20</td>
<td>X17</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>X80</td>
<td>X84</td>
<td>V28</td>
<td>X02</td>
<td>X12</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>X22</td>
<td>X55</td>
<td>V57</td>
<td>U15</td>
<td>V29</td>
<td>X51</td>
<td>X40</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

I would like to take one < tr > and insert it into an excel sheet/dataframe so it could follow this format,

```
            Table_Title             
            X68 X20 X17     
        X80 X84 V28 X02 X12 
    X22 X55 V57 U15 V29 X51 X40
```

Using BeautifulSoup I was able to find all the tables I want to extract using the following

```
with open(r'D:\yolo\frolo\dolo.html','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents.encode("UTF8"),'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'table'})
```

From here, I have attempted to extract everything in between < tr > but I am unaware of a way to do so while maintaining the integrity of the rows.

For example, I have tried

```
for i in table:
    for k in i:
        text = i.get_text().split('\n')
        print(text)
```

but will return iterations like this.

```
['Table_Title']
['', '', ' ', ' ', 'X68', 'X20', 'X17', ' ', ' ', 
'', '', ' ', 'X80', 'X84', 'V28', 'X02', 'X12', ' ', 
'', '', 'X22', 'X55', 'V57', 'U15', 'V29', 'X51', 'X40',
'', '', 'X14', 'W05', 'T34', 'U36', 'T38', 'S75', 'X24', 
'', '', 'X83', 'X57', 'U48', 'V10', 'T82', 'X04', 'X11',
'', '', ' ', 'X82', 'X59', 'T39', 'X03', 'X18', ' ', '',
'', ' ', ' ', 'X78', 'X15', 'X41', ' ', ' ', '', '']
```

I have also tried,

```
table.find_all('td')
```

Which returns,

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. 
You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. 
Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

The closest I have gotten is getting the data in a list using

```
k.contents
```

When I attempt to us regular expressions

```
print(re.findall("<tr>(.*?)</tr>", "".join(k.contents)))
```

I get this,

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Tag found
```

In summary, this is my initial code and I was hoping to get some guidance on how to move from here.

```
with open(r'D:\yolo\frolo\dolo.html','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents.encode("UTF8"),'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'table'})
```

I am new to BeautifulSoup and html and was hoping someone could help extract these rows. Does BeautifulSoup have a feature that I can use to extract the table row by row?

Hopefully I communicated this clearly and I apologize for the long post. just trying to equip everyone with enough information to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will store the data for each table in its own list and store the data for each row under that table in its own list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="FA_DSC"><p>Table_Title</p><table border="1" cellpadding="4"style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td>X68</td>
<td>X20</td>
<td>X17</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>X80</td>
<td>X84</td>
<td>V28</td>
<td>X02</td>
<td>X12</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>X22</td>
<td>X55</td>
<td>V57</td>
<td>U15</td>
<td>V29</td>
<td>X51</td>
<td>X40</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

data = []
for table in soup.select('table'):
    table_data = []
    data.append(table_data)
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        row_data = []
        table_data.append(row_data)
        for td in tr.select('td'):
            row_data.append(td.get_text())

print(data)
```

Output

```
[[[' ', ' ', 'X68', 'X20', 'X17', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'X80', 'X84', 'V28', 'X02', 'X12', ' '], ['X22', 'X55', 'V57', 'U15', 'V29', 'X51', 'X40']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

```
import pandas as pd

html="""<div id="FA_DSC"><p>Table_Title</p><table border="1" cellpadding="4"style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td>X68</td>
<td>X20</td>
<td>X17</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>X80</td>
<td>X84</td>
<td>V28</td>
<td>X02</td>
<td>X12</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>X22</td>
<td>X55</td>
<td>V57</td>
<td>U15</td>
<td>V29</td>
<td>X51</td>
<td>X40</td>
</tr>
</table></div>"""
pd.read_html(html)
```

Out:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  NaN  NaN  X68  X20  X17  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  X80  X84  V28  X02  X12  NaN
2  X22  X55  V57  U15  V29  X51  X40
```